# How to compile a angular component or template in the memory without injecting in the view and get the innerHTML?

Tags: angular, angular8, jspdf

I want to compile component A in the component B memory without rendering it into the dom. then i should be able to get the innerHTML of the component A. component A has markdown content parsed with marked pipe.

Component A - has static structure and dynamic content

```
<div #componentA>Component A- {{markdown content | markedPipe}}</div>
```

Component B - wants to compile component/template A and get the innerHTML.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b',
  template: '<button (click)="downloadAToPDF()"></button>'
})
export class ComponentB{

  downloadAToPDF() {
     // const innerHTML = CompileAPI(ComponentA)
     const pdf = new jsPdf()
     pdf.fromHTML(innerHTML,15,15,{})
     pdf.save()
  }

}
```

Comment: You are passing HTML in `templateUrl` property of `@Component` decorator. Use `template` instead of `templateUrl` or add HTML to template and link that here.

Comment: @AhmadRaza Thanks i have corrected it.